What is the distribution of the time complexity for the randomized selection (Quickselect) algorithm?
I'm studying the randomized selection algorithm, also known as Quickselect, which is used to find the k-th smallest element in an unordered list. The algorithm can be defined as follows:
FUNCTION randomised_select(A, p, r, i):
    IF p = r THEN
        RETURN A[p]
    
    q = partition(A, p, r)
    k = q - p + 1
    
    IF i = k THEN
        RETURN A[q]
    ELSE IF i < k THEN
        RETURN randomised_select(A, p, q - 1, i)
    ELSE
        RETURN randomised_select(A, q + 1, r, i - k)

FUNCTION partition(A, p, r):
    pivot_index = RANDOM_INTEGER(p, r)  // Select random pivot index
    SWAP A[pivot_index] WITH A[r]       // Move pivot to the end
    x = A[r]                             // Set pivot value
    i = p - 1                            // Initialize index for smaller elements
    
    FOR j FROM p TO r - 1 DO
        IF A[j] <= x THEN
            i = i + 1
            SWAP A[i] WITH A[j]         // Swap elements to partition
    END FOR
    
    SWAP A[i + 1] WITH A[r]             // Place pivot in the correct position
    RETURN i + 1                        // Return the pivot index

I have seen that its expected time complexity is O(n), but I'm curious about how this time complexity is distributed. Are there any empirical studies or theoretical analyses that detail this distribution?
